# basic haskell: error with simple function

Tags: haskell

I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, but when I try and run it I get

```
Couldn't match type `Integer' with `Int'
```

I'm using GHCi. I want to create a basic program that will go through the shop and give me all the customer names so I can then do a search to find out what item they have rented (a library). Is there a better way of getting the names?

This is my code:

```
type Name = String
type Customer = (Name,Int)
type shop = [Customer]
shop = [cust1, cust2]

cust1 = ("Neil", 311)
cust2 = ("Fred", 0)

getName :: (String,Int) -> Name
getName (a,b) = a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GHCi will default to using `Integer` over `Int`.  You should specify the type of your tuples as `cust1 = ("Neil", 311 :: Int)` or `cust2 = ("Fred", 0) :: (String, Int)`.

**Edit after updates**

If you already have `Customer` defined, you should write it as

```
cust1 = ("Neil", 311) :: Customer
cust2 = ("Fred", 0) :: Customer

getName :: Customer -> Name
getName (a, b) = a
```

You could also simplify things a bit by defining `getName` as

```
getName :: Customer -> Name
getName = fst
```

using ETA reduction and the built-in function `fst`

Comment: Thanks, you're always so helpful!
I changed the function + declaration of the types instead so I don't have to do it everytime plus it's not essential for it to be Int instead of Integer.

Comment: No problem!  Just remember to accept, that way others can see if an answer is solved =)